# Array in C language

Tags: c, arrays

```
int m=10,n=5,a[10]={10,15,20};

void f1(void);
void f2(int m);

main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
       f1();
    f2(1);
    printf("\n%d,%d",a[m],a[n]);
    system("pause");
}

void f1(void)
{
    static int n=3;
    a[n]=a[n-1]+a[n-2]+a[n-3];n++;
}

void f2(int m)
{
    for(;m<3;m+=2)
    {
        int m;
        for(m=1;m<4;m++)
            printf("%d,",a[m++]);
    }
}
```

the out put is 
15,45,
10,145

Who can explain why a[m]=10? 
Is array titled "a" within up to a[9]?

Comment: You have three different variables called 'm'. Are you printing the one you intend? At the end, you print a[10] (since the global m is unchanged by your program), which is undefined as it's off the end of your array. Have you tried stepping through it to see what it does, maybe by hand? Because it's not at all clear what it's supposed to do!

Comment: In function `f2(int)` there is parameter `m` and local `int m;`. Which `m` do you refer?

Comment: The variable title the same name is the point on which our homework test us. The a[10] is the output, but a[10] is beyond the limit!

Comment: yes, a[10] is beyond the limit and it's undefined what value that has. So the program is incorrect. Again, what is your question?

Comment: My question is: why a[10]=10?

Comment: Who knows? It's undefined. It's probably because the compiler decides to put the space for m there? But it really is undefined - the compiler is free to have the program crash, produce the wrong value, cause snow to fall in New York, anything.

Comment: Nice of you! It is strange that my classmate's computer shows the same  output. What's your output? Maybe this is a Easter egg？

Comment: No, it's not an Easter egg, it's merely undefined. It happens as Kang Li said, to be the value of 'n' but with a different compiler, or different flags to the compiler, or just the next time it's compiled with the same compiler, it could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through gdb trace you can know why a[10] is 10 in the last. But in fact this behavior is actually undefined.

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000cc4: file static_var.c, line 11.
(gdb) b f2
Breakpoint 2 at 0x100000e3b: file static_var.c, line 26.
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, main () at static_var.c:11
11              for(i=0;i<7;i++)
(gdb) x a
0x100001080 <a>:    0x0000000a
(gdb) x a+10
0x1000010a8 <n.1907>:   0x00000003
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, f2 (m=1) at static_var.c:26
26          for(;m<3;m+=2)
(gdb) x a
0x100001080 <a>:    0x0000000a
(gdb) x a+10
0x1000010a8 <n.1907>:   0x0000000a
```

The value of a[10] is actually access static variable n in f1 function. After

```
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
       f1();
```

Global variable n inside f1 grow to 10 .ie 0xa. So a[10] turn out to be 10.

Comment: Kang Li, are you Chinese? You name looks as if you were from China.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a Chinese and I live in Beijing now. What's up?

Answer (score 3):

C/C++ compiler do not bound check for arrays. But behavior is unpredictable. It may corrupt memory, or it may crash, or it may run without any error.

Comment: I compiled it. The output is right according to the answer in the back of the homework.

Comment: @user3368061, did you write the program? (because its behaviour is undefined). Or where you asked to explain it? If you wrote it, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: So if the output is right, what is your question? Walk through the program by hand, or add more printfs and see what it does. However, if you were given that program as is, I'm surprised as it's very poorly written.

Comment: I change the code to this:   printf("\n%d,%d,%d",a[m],a[n],m);  the out put is 15,45,  10,145,10

Comment: @user3368061 “It is a homework" does not answer the question “did you write the program” or were you given this program, written by someone else, to explain?

Comment: The codes are given, and I have type them in my compiler to compile it. The output is what the answer also shows. My question is why a[10]=10.